# How can I run multiple TestNG xmls via TestNG SuiteRunner class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

Is it possible to run multiple to run multiple TestNG xmls via TestNG SuiteRunner class. 
I created below Runner Class:

```java
package com.util;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.TestNG;
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG runner           = new TestNG();
        List<String> suitefiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        suitefiles.add("<path of Xml 1>");
        suitefiles.add("<path of Xml 2>");
        runner.setDefaultSuiteName("test");
        runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);
        runner.run();
    }
}
```

Following error occurred on executing above class file:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:320)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021)
at com.util.Runner.main(Runner.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:712)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
    ... 2 more
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: What version of TestNG are you working with ? Can you please try this again with the latest released version of TestNG (6.12 as of now)

Comment: Currently I am using 6.9.4 version. Could you suggest if the Runner class I attached above is correct or not?

Comment: I dont think its the runners. I think its perhaps the xml that could be an issue. Can you please edit your question and add the xml contents as well ?